How to python Scrape a dropdown span tag
I am trying to get the Xpath of a span element which in this case is a dropdown menu. How am I suppose to make it work? I tried a lot of things. This is the URL: https://search.et.gr/el/.
I tried to import to the code an xlsx file with a list of "Έτος", "Τεύχος" and "Αριθμός Φ.Ε.Κ" values in order to automatically download pdfs. So I got the Xpath for each of these but except of "Αριθμός Φ.Ε.Κ" I cannot figure out what to do with the other "Έτος" and "Τεύχος" which are dropdowns span elements.
